# Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'

Tags: asp-classic

I receive the following error when there is no value for querystring. (I mean like index.asp?ID=).

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'

index.asp, line 10

I tried converting NULL value to something else with the following code. It did not work.

```
MEMBERID        = Request.QueryString("ID")

If MEMBERID = "" or MEMBERID = 0 Then
    MEMBERID = Session("MEMBERID")
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't the String comparison functions be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you're getting the parameter ID from the QueryString and checking if it's empty or zero, right? So, you should do something like:

```
MemberId = Request.QueryString("ID")
'*
'* Check for other than numbers just to be safe
'*
If (MemberId = "" Or Not IsNumeric(MemberId)) Then
   MemberId = Session("MemberId")
End If
'*
'* We can't add this check on the above if because
'* in classic ASP, the expression is evaluated as a whole
'* which would generate an exception when converting to Int
'*
If (CInt(MemberId) = 0) Then
   MemberId = Session("MemberId")
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a null to an empty string, use the string concatenation operator `&`:

```
MEMBERID = Request.QueryString("ID") & ""
```

Comment: QueryString never returns a null.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case, the code was like this:

```
if TRIM(variavel) <> "0" then
    variavel = "1"
end if
```

And the "default" solution here where i work is:

```
if isNull(variavel) then
    variavel = "1"
end if
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Nothing:

```
IF Request.QueryString("ID") IS Nothing Then
 ...
End If
```

Comment: QueryString.Item never returns a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:-

```
 dim memberID : memberID = Request.QueryString("ID")
 if memberID <> "" then memberID = CLng(memberID)
 if memberID = Empty then memberID = Session("MemberID")
```

The QueryString item property returns either an `Empty` or a `String`.  It will never return a integer.

If memberID is not parsable as an integer then this code will error.  However, if the value on ID is supposed to be an integer but is actually something else then I would want it to fail.

`Empty` compares as equal to both zero-length string and numeric 0.